# How can I create a friendship that must be approved with the Relation module?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to learn how to use the [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module.  The [Node One Screencasts](http://dev.nodeone.se/node/970) are very helpful in showing how to set up a "User A and B are friends" type relation.  However, most SNS sites require friends to approve each other.

How would one go about setting up an approval mechanism?  The rules module?  What, roughly speaking, would such a set up look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules is just a handy "programmatic tool" (and API) to encapsulate things. Relation is a way to express -- well Relations.

In my opinion, using just relation and either Views or RelationQuery or EntityFieldQuery you can come up with what you need.

You just need more than 1 Relation.

Something like 1 relation of:
UserA <- are_friends -> UserB

to express a global "friends list" of users within your site. You could make another relation a_user <- has_friends -> user(s) which could be 1 users friends list.

Another relation:
UserA <- is_a_friend_request -> UserB (1-way relationship)

The is_a_friend_request relation could have an attached field of 'request_status' which is a "select list" field type for instance with "approved" and "denied" or "ignore" as options.

A view could be made to show to any user of their "friend_requests". Acting on a friend request adds a recipient user to a given user's "are_friends" relationship.

I'm not sure if this is a naive way of looking at your problem ... you could definately use rules in there somewhere ... but its not a necessity.